# jQuery masonry with ion.tabs, using masonry with different (tab) containers on same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

Here a link to JSFiddle showing my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/robkom/T73QK/23/

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    // https://github.com/IonDen/ion.tabs

    $.ionTabs("#tabs_group");


    // http://masonry.desandro.com/, http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

    var $container1 = $(".ionTabs__body").find("[data-name=tab1]");
    $container1.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container1.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            transitionDuration: 0
        })
    });

    var $container2 = $(".ionTabs__body").find("[data-name=tab2]");
    $container2.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container2.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            transitionDuration: 0
        })
    });

    var $container3 = $(".ionTabs__body").find("[data-name=tab3]");
    $container3.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container3.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            transitionDuration: 0
        })
    });


});
```

I am using jQuery 1.11.0, and the jQuery plugins Masonry and Ion.Tabs. Basically, each tab is a container that has square divs which I want to be arranged in a masonry fashion.

There are three tabs and even though I initialize Masonry on each tab separately, it seems to only take affect on the first tab. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? The other two tabs should look like the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/robkom/T73QK/35/

I had to add the following code:

```
$('.ionTabs__tab').click(function(){
    var $container = $(".ionTabs__item");
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.box',
            transitionDuration: 0
        });
    });
});
```